# C++ use lock/unlock

Tags: c++, memory, locking

I got an array which typed as stack.
Every core managed it own indexes on the array. For example core 1 index 1-4 and core 2 index 5-10. The cores processing at the same time the array. do I need to lock the array? It does not process the same information. Sorry about my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's interesting that your cores are female. In any case, you only need to lock shared data between threads. If each thread messes with different data, there is no need.